# Will my turnips rot if I visit another island that has time-travelled?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I know that if I set my system time back to the past, any turnips that I have will rot.

But if I am visiting another island, and that player has his system time set to the past or to the future, do my turnips back in my home island rot when I return back to my own island and my own system time?

Comment: but why do the turnips rot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've travelled to another island set to February 2021 (it is May 2021 at the time of writing this). My turnips at home are fine. It seems time travelling to the past through someone else's island does not rot your turnips.

Comment: I guess the game check date difference only for your game and don't check when you go to someone else island.